# Repeating a record twice

Tags: java, jdbc

I am fetching rows from DB using following function in JDBC. I have two records in DB but it prints only one record twice. And that is the record which is at the end. Why is that so?

```
public List<Student> getRows() throws SQLException {

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/something", "root", "root");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student");
        Student tmp = new Student();

        while (rs.next()) {

            tmp.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            tmp.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            list.add(tmp);
        }

        return list;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are adding the `student` to the `list`, you are passing the student by reference rather than by value because that is how java works. So when you change it again the second time the loop runs, it changes the first entry in the list because it it is pointing to the student still. You need to do something like list.add(new Student(student.getID(), student.getName()) or you could new student each time the loop runs (this would be better practice I think).

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        student.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        list.add(student);
    }
```